# How can I make named_scope in Rails return one value instead of an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, find

I want to write a [named scope](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#M001684) to get a record from its id.

For example, I have a model called `Event`, and I want to simulate `Event.find(id)` with use of `named_scope` for future flexibility.

I used this code in my model:

```
named_scope :from_id, lambda { |id| {:conditions => ['id= ?', id] } }
```

and I call it from my controller like `Event.from_id(id)`.  But my problem is that it returns an array of `Event` objects instead of just one object.

Thus if I want to get event name, I have to write

```
event = Event.from_id(id)
event[0].name
```

while what I want is

```
event = Event.from_id(id)
event.name
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Damien mentions, using a custom scope just to look up by ID isn't advisable. But to answer your question:

Finding records with `named_scope` will always return an `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope` object, which behaves like an array. If there is just a single record returned by your query, you can use the `first` method to get the ActiveRecord object directly, like this:

```
event = Event.from_id(id).first
event.name # will work as you expect
```

Comment: hi Jimmy

Thanks for the quick answer. Why I want to have a named scope is (as I mentioned in Damien's comment)

because later I might want to get only the active events So then I can change only the named scope with out breaking the existing code (like only adding active=1) Please let me know your comments cheers, sameera

Answer (score 13):

In this case I'd create a class method

```
def self.from_id(id)
  self.find(id).first
end
```

Another example:

```
class Invoice
  def self.number
    self.find(:first, 
      :select => "max(number) As last, max(number)+1 As next", 
      :conditions => "type = 'SalesOrder'")
  end
end
```

Methods like this its better then named_scope. You can call `Invoice.number.next`, better than `named_scope` return `Invoice.number[0].next`.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to use a scope here. You could just do `Event.find_by_id id`.
The difference between `find` and `find_by_id` is that the first one will raise an `ActiveRecordNotFoundException` if the record does not exist. The second one will just return nil.

Writing a scope to get the record by it's id is a very bad id as it is something which is already provided natively by rails.

Comment: Hi Damien,

thanks for the quick reply. Why i want to have this as a named scope is because later I might want to get only the active events

So then I can change only the named scope with out breaking the existing code (like only adding active=1)

Please let me know your comments

cheers,
sameera

Comment: @sameera you could just add a generic method (`def ... end`); it doesn't have to be a named scope.